# Disable KDE pop-up when switching keyboard layouts

Tags: kde, opensuse, keyboard-layout

When I switch keyboard layouts in KDE (KDE Plasma 5.8 in OpenSUSE 42.3) using `Ctrl-Alt-K`, it not only changes the indicator in the bottom right, but it also displays a pop-up in the middle of the screen. It stays there for several seconds during which I cannot write and work, because I can't see what's below. How to disable that?

[image: the popup]

Comment: maybe the following link is relevant for you?:
[kde.org/...](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=131991)

Comment: Looks like it may be it. However when I do `locate Osd.qml` it founds it only for 2 themes, but neither of them is th one I use. I use Oxygen.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I use the standard breeze theme, and it works like a charm.